# how to find start and last from sequence value sql

Tags: sql

Given the following input data:

| id | seq | date | Serial Num | wh | amount | supp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 557 | 79264887 | 2023-07-25 | 1000990036512 | 82 | 14209 | 1709 |
| 557 | 79264888 | 2023-07-25 | 1000990036513 | 82 | 14209 | 1709 |
| 557 | 79264889 | 2023-07-25 | 1000990036514 | 82 | 14209 | 1709 |
| 557 | 79264890 | 2023-07-25 | 1000990036515 | 82 | 14209 | 1709 |
| 557 | 79264891 | 2023-07-25 | 1000990036516 | 82 | 14209 | 1709 |
| 557 | 79264892 | 2023-07-25 | 1000990036517 | 82 | 14209 | 1709 |
| 557 | 79264893 | 2023-07-25 | 1000990036518 | 82 | 14209 | 1709 |

How can I make the output to look like as follows?

| id | date | start serial | end serial | wh | amount | supp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 557 | 2023-07-25 | 1000990036512 | 1000990036518 | 82 | 14209 | 1709 |

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: yeaa thanks for fixed my question, im beginner in here :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
select id, date, wh, amount, supp, min(serial_num) as start_serial, 
       max(serial_num) as end_serial
  from mytable
 group by id, date, wh, amount, supp
                
   ID DATE               WH     AMOUNT       SUPP START_SERIAL    END_SERIAL
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------------
  557 2023-07-25         82      14209       1709 1000990036512   1000990036518
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, there is this analytic function called `FIRST_VALUE` & `LAST_VALUE`, you can use these functions to get the first and last values. The SQL code should look something like this.

```
SELECT id, date,
    FIRST_VALUE(N'Serial Num') OVER (
        PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq
        ) AS N'start serial',
    LAST_VALUE(N'Serial Num') OVER (
        PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq
        ) AS N'end serial',
    wh,
    amount,
    supp
FROM your_table 
WHERE ID = 557 AND WH = 82;
```